# Discord.py -- Make the same command with different parameters resulting in different outcomes

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to discord.py.

@bot.command(pass_context=True)

```
async def AddToDo(ctx, ToDoItem):
    if(ctx.message.author.name not in ToDoList):
        temporaryList.append(ToDoItem)
        ToDoList[ctx.message.author.name] = temporaryList
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully added {ToDoItem} to your To Do List!")
```

The above code works fine. I want to add a message correcting the user when the user types '$AddToDo' with no parameters. How do I do that?

Note: My code doesn't contain a class, but I can add one. I'll need some help with the syntax, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use command local error handlers.
For example:

```
@AddToDo.error
async def AddToDo_error(ctx, error):
        error = getattr(error, 'original', error)
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
           await ctx.send("Missing arguments")
```